# AppLinks for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, applinks

when I click an applink,I need to chose the chrome or my app

[image]

I Check my website [Google Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator)
i got below

```
Success! Host XXX grants app deep linking to XXX.
```

But adb shell dumpsys package domain-preferred-apps
shows

```
"Status: undefined"
```

## Anyone knows how to fix it?

Manifest.xml
`

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="XXXX.XX"
                android:path="/test" />
        </intent-filter>`
```

the applinks status is not "always"  how to make it right???

```
"Status: undefined"
```

Comment: Are you using ActivityChooser in our code ?

Comment: no . I want to do this when I click the html link my Android app launch

Answer (score 0):

put this code on TextView  onClick Listener..

```
String urlString="http://www.google.com";
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
try {
context.startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
// Chrome browser presumably not installed so allow user to choose instead
intent.setPackage(null);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

}

Comment: This is a webpage ,not in my app

Comment: The question is how to setup my android app!!!  the webpage is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid seeing the chooser, you need to set up Verified App Links. See [here](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links/) for instructions